# Replacing Key-List in Free format SQLRPGLE

Tags: rpgle

I am converting RPGLE fixed format to Free format and while converting i got a issue the KEY-LIST & Fields got converted into Data-structure. which is basically redefining fields which are already defined either directly or indirectly...

```
DCL-DS Key_List;                                                                               
     Field1 CHAR(4);                                                                            
     Field2 CHAR(4);  
END-DS;
```

both field1 & field2 are file's fields. below is old style (fixed format)

```
C     Key_list      KLIST                           
C                   KFLD                    Field1
C                   KFLD                    Field2
```

Please Advice...program is giving compile time error (SQL0314) field1 & field are not Unique

Answer (score 5):

You can use %kds() with a data structured defined with `EXTNAME(...:*KEY)` or `LIKEREC(...:*KEY)`

```
dcl-ds key_list likerec(myfileR:*key);
//
chain %kds(key_list) myfile;
```

Or simply use the fields directly since they are already defined...

```
chain (field1:field2) myfile;
```

Either method should get rid of the duplicate define and stop the SQL0314 error from the pre-compiler.